# Get reference of multiple views in a row of recyclerview

Tags: android

I use a click listener interface to get reference to clicked view and the adapter row position and pass these to activity which contains the recyclerview. I handle click events there. I think this is how most of us handle recyclerview clicks , right ? Now i what i need is , upon a click, get reference of not only the clicked view , but also reference of another view in that row.

Currently i have these passed to activity : View clickedview , int position

I need this : View clickedview , int position , view anotherviewInThatRowWhichIsntClicked

Help needed thanks

Comment: Can you get the parent of the clicked view?

Comment: Yes i can. A relativelayout

Comment: Okay, so you should be able to findViewById on that to get the other view, right?

Comment: That results in getting the view, but in all rows. For example, changing color , changes color of that view in every row

Comment: You shouldn't modify the views from the Activity. That's why the adapter is there. Modify the state of the dataset that the adapter has, and notify the adapter that something has changed, preferably with the `notifyItemChanged(int pos)`method instead of the more general `notifyDatasetChanged`

Comment: @GSala I'm already using adapter for that. There are situations when view should be modified in activity

Comment: @user6650650 What's the situation? The state of the view should never be modified from the activity. The view would be recycled after scrolling and the changes would be lost.

Comment: That isn't about this question mate

Comment: the 'changing color' was just  an example. To be more specific , I will use the view references as a shared element transition parameter

Comment: thats why I need it. else , shared element transition animates the view in wrong row